# Can I ask a duplicate question to ask if the answer has changed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I was searching for an answer to a question about an Android problem. I did find a solution, so I upvoted and was satisfied... until I noticed that the question and answer are both from 2012. Given that many things can change in 3 and a half years, I'm not sure I should entirely trust that answer.

But I'm not sure what action to take. The answerer seems no longer active on SO, so if I comment asking about updates I'm not likely to get a response. Is it acceptable to ask a new question, link to this as a possible duplicate and explain that I'd like to know if anything has changed since then? Or is that a questionable approach to asking a question?

Comment: Why not simply ask via a comment on the answer if the answer if still up-to-date? Even if they are no longer active on Stack Overflow, another user may see the answer and update it. You could also ask in a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) to see if the answer if up-to-date, and if anyone can improve or update it.

Comment: If you want new input on an old question, bounty it

Comment: "I'm not sure I should entirely trust that answer" - so what do you fear? That three years later the solution is going to trigger a newly added self-destruct sequence? I'd think that you can recognize yourself if the solution is still to be trusted - you judge by the results.

Comment: @Gimby I'm quite a novice with Android so if there's pitfalls or poor practices I'd like to know. The solution in the answer seemed a bit hacky, perhaps that should have been in my question.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I hate to keep pushing, but did you research into this yourself at all, or did you not do that "because you're a novice"? To me the best possible outcome of this is not you asking if there is a slicker solution, but you **providing** it - when the time is right. Which is maybe not right now. I've spent the last 30 minutes rewriting this comment to not sound like a douche. I hope I succeeded.

Comment: @Gimby You don't come off badly, don't worry. I have not researched it yet, but I'm going to before I do anything else (aside from having commented on the off chance the original author reappears). I was pre-emptively asking this so I have an answer if I'm unable to turn anything up with research. Of course if I come up with an answer I have confidence in I'll post it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your question would be along the lines of "I found this answer, is it up to date?", the answer would be *no*. Even if you submitted an identical question, it will be closed as a duplicate of the question you linked (you *might* be able to get away with "I found this question, but its answers are outdated because...").

[As jonrsharpe said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308032/can-i-ask-a-duplicate-question-to-ask-if-the-answer-has-changed#comment258372_308032), if you need an old question updated, you can apply [a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a
> bounty may help attract more attention and more answers. Slice off
> anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and
> [attach it to any question as a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties). You do not need to be the asker
> of the question to offer a bounty on it.

Placing a bounty as (I think) "answer is outdated or needs clarification" should be sufficient. It may even attract new answers as well as the OP updating the current one.

A few other things you could do:

- Ask the OP via a comment to update the answer, or clarify that it is still up-to-date
- Bring the answer to the attention of a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) and ask for it to be updated, or confirmation that it is still up-to-date

Part of the edit process is **keeping answers up-to-date**, therefore even users with sub-2k reputation will be able to update the answer via suggested edits. Remember that if you're going to edit something yourself to update/add details to it, ***ensure you use a good edit summary*** (otherwise your edit will probably be rejected).

Comment: But what is the point of putting a bounty on a question that has an accepted/upvoted answer already? Won't the old accepted/upvoted answer automatically steal that bounty from any new answer from others (assuming the new answers can't catch up in votes quickly enough to the old one before the bounty is awarded)?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - The automatic award is only granted for answers [given _after_ the bounty starts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/305827). The bounty can still be awarded manually to an existing/updated question.  If there are no new answers, and the bounty isn't manually awarded, then it's not awarded and the reputation evaporates.