# Is using backticks for inline quotes acceptable?

Tags: discussion

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308034/1709587) is on the verge of starting an edit war over backtick usage. Josh Caswell says:

> Backticks are for [inline *code* elements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (also see the generated HTML); please do not use them for highlighting or quote markup.

But the post's author says:

> @JoshCaswell They are also often used for quotations inline where it is not possible to add quotes. I have rolled back the edit and do not wish for an edit war- please do not touch my answers again.

Is the post's author's usage of backticks for quotation acceptable, or should they be edited out?

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149464/159251

Comment: Just to note, it wouldn't have turned into an edit war: I wasn't going to roll it back again. One edit to correct the problem, one rollback plus comment to clarify why the edit was proper. (If I'd thought it was a big enough deal -- probably not in this case -- I would have raised a flag at that point.)

Answer (score 12):

Accepted answer to [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) on MSO by [Dave Newton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168933/dave-newton), reproduced here for your viewing pleasure:

> Correct, they should be used for code (and code-like artifacts).
>
> If that's the only change, and it's wrongly applied, reject as "no improvement whatsoever" or "causes harm".
>
> I don't have a problem with filenames, paths, API methods, commands, etc.–those are computery "artifacts" that should be differentiated from expository text. Products, trademarks, etc. aren't.
>
> When emphasis or clarification is needed for non-artifacts we have italics and bold.

Comment: This doesn't explicitly address quotes, though.

Comment: Well, "they should be used for code and code-like artifacts", there's bold and italic for other uses.

Comment: @MarkAmery It says that code markup should only be used for code, and that it shouldn't be used for non-code content.  The quote isn't code, thus this applies.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with plain-old quote-marks?

Comment: There's also `>` for embedding quotes clearly into posts.

Answer (score 4):

My opinion: no, this is not okay. Code formatting is horrible for quotes; instead, italicise and wrap the quote in actual speech marks.

Posts that use backticks in this way should be edited, and if the author rolls back the edit, they should be flagged.

Comment: You're going to flag someone for misusing backticks? That's overkill.

Comment: @mmking no - I'd flag them for wrongly rolling back a good edit.

Comment: No need.  rollback wars are auto flagged.

Comment: @NathanOliver When something is (incorrectly) rolled back once there's no mod flag.  There's need to be *another* roll back for a mod to see it.

Comment: @Servy I know that that is why I said *rollback wars*.  a single rollback is not a rollback war

Comment: @NathanOliver And in this situation one person rolled back an appropriate edit.  Thus your choices are either rollback the edit again, *starting* a rollback war which would cause a mod flag, or just flagging a mod *without starting a rollback war*.  You should do the latter.

Comment: @Servy Why?  don't we want the correct edit being shown or is it not worth it as the other user will just rollback again.  I should also point on that in this situation the post was rolled back several times.

Comment: @NathanOliver Why, because you don't want to start a rollback war.  Don't assume that the other person is going to be the one to give up and wait for a mod, be the bigger person and leave and let the mod do their job.

Comment: A slight disagreement here, @Servy; I believe that the route I took -- _one single_ reinstatement of my edit plus a clarifying/emphasizing comment -- is better than an immediate flag, because ideally a mod should not need to get involved. _Then_, if my comment does not convince, and I notice and still care enough, a flag would be the only appropriate choice. I don't need to call the cops the instant my neighbor parks his motorcycle on my side of the property line -- first I should just ask him to please move it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Your analogy is appropriate for the first edit, but you're advocating making the edit a second time.  If you want to post a comment explaining why their rollback was inappropriate, that's fine, but starting a rollback war just isn't productive.  *Either* talk it out or let a mod handle it *without* starting a rollback war.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: **From now-on I'll use quotation marks.**

I admit it:

[image]

*Let me explain why I didn't*:

I used the `code` function for quotations I wanted noticed, I *did not* previously use backticks for entire lines:

`I didn't do this, because in my opinion this is stupid and there's already a function for it.`

However (in my opinion), using backticks for quotations **where the said function cannot be used** is acceptable. For example, using them in this sentence `like this` is fine. I personally do not like the use of actual "quotations" as I see it as sarcasm, but maybe that's just me.

I also did research it, and it seems that there is a [mixed opinion on using `backticks` inline for quotations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262466/2422013):

> I do so too from time to time, and would have left your answer alone.
>
> However, in the general case, code formatting is indeed abused to
>   highlight arbitrary words sometimes, and that usage should be edited.

The [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262466/2422013) from which I pinched that excerpt from is (currently) at +7/-20, so it seems more users are *against* this behaviour, but a small minority are for it.

*I've been here for a while, but I'm still willing to put my hands up and take the blame for this (rightly), we all make mistakes.*

Comment: It's certainly not the end of the world -- not something I think you need to actually _apologize_ for. I hope I didn't antagonize you, either.